# C++ creating hdc on dilogex control on external dll

Tags: c++, dll, dialog

In my main program I have a dialg box that contains many controls.
One of them is a static control in witch I want to draw an image with a text on and some transparency effect.

Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

You should consider deriving your own class from **CStatic**. You should define the static control with the **SS_OWNERDRAW** style, so you will be able to handle its rendering in `CStatic::DrawItem`. When `DrawItem` is called, you will receive a pointer to the `DrawItemStruct`, which has embedded in it, a handle to the control's DC that you can use to render into the control.

I'd also suggest looking at this implementation: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9064/Yet-Another-Transparent-Static-Control